# How to change position of the document in a collection itself in mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native

**For example,

I have collection like this in mongo db,

```
[

  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "key": 1
  },

  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "key": 2
  },

  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "key": 3
  },

   {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "key": 4
  }
]
```

Expected result,

I want this result like this in collection itself

```
[

  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "key": 4
  },

  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "key": 1
  },

  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "key": 2
  },

   {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "key": 3
  }
]
```

How to archive this in mongodb?**

Comment: why do you want that kind of collection in DB?

Comment: The short answer is that you don't. The database is free to store the data however it believes is most efficient. But the details of how things are stored internally should not be relevant to your usage of the system as an end user. If your goal is to get results of your queries sorted in the specified manner then that is achievable, but we would need more details about the specifics of the desired ordering.